# C# to Save Excel AsCopy

Tags: c#, excel

After some testing, it appears there are few issues.

This code is now copying the file.. After the `File.Copy` operation, there is code following that should update certain cells, when attempting to update, it systems falls over with an error advising it cant find that specific cell A28 for example.

When reverting my code back to simply overwriting the original, it finds the cell - A28 and updates the value with no issues.

Any ideas?

Code as is stands (with overwriting original Template):

```
// Declaration of variables 
ClientName = txtClientName.Text;

string newFileName = ClientName + ".xls";

string Filename = "C:\\Template.xls";

//File.Copy(Filename, @"C:\\" + newFileName, true);


// If you are using xls format (2003), use this connection string.

string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\"";

string SQL1 = "UPDATE [Cover Sheet$A28:A28] SET F1='" + ClientName + "'";

using (OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            Connection.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(SQL1, Connection))
            {
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass to your procedure the name of the new file name desired, copy the template and work on the new file.

```
public void MapToExcelDocument(string newFileName) 
{ 
    // Declaration of variables  
    string templateName = "C:\\Template.xls"; 
    File.Copy(templateName, newFileName, true);

    // If you are using xls format (2003), use this connection string.             
    string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + 
                               newFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\""; 

 ....
```

This change (Calling File.Copy) requires the adding of this line to the beginning of the source code file:

```
using System.IO;
```

This simple line inform the compiler that you are using objects, classes, enums and interfaces present in the System.IO namespace. Without the line you should prefix every class like File with its fully qualified namespace

```
System.IO.FileCopy(templateName, newFileName, true);
```

not very typing convenient as you can see.

EDIT: Following the comments below I will add another tip.
If you pass in a simple file name without path, the File.Copy creates the new file in the current working directory. The current working directory When you are working within Visual Studio is `bin/debug` or `bim/release`. When you deploy your application, the current working directory will be the directory where your application starts.

You have some options:

- Pass a fully qualified filename to an arbitrary directory (I.E.
  "C:\MyFiles\destinationFile.xls").
- Define a path inside your config file and add this path to the
  filename passed in.
- Define a relative path in your config file and write in a
  directory relative to a well known paths (like MyDocuments)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the compiler is not liking 'File': The name File does not exist within the current context.

Comment: Add the `using System.IO;` at the beginning of your source code.

Comment: Added the above line. No compiler issues however, new file is not being created.

Comment: Have you passed a full qualified filename? Have you changed the connection string?

Comment: public void MapToExcelDocument()
        {
            // Declaration of variables 
            ClientName = txtClientName.Text;
            string newFileName = ClientName + ".xls";

            string Filename = "C:\\Template.xls";

            File.Copy(Filename, newFileName, true);

            // If you are using xls format (2003), use this connection string.            
            string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + newFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\"";

Comment: Sorry for pasting as per my previous post, where is a 'Reply' button or similar on this board?

Comment: Ok, after a big of digging.. The Application is successfully creating a new file with the new filename. However, it is being saved within the projects bin/debug folder.. Can i specify to save in C://

Comment: Of course, if you pass a simple file name without path, the File.Copy creates the new file in the current working directory. When you are working within Visual Studio this is bin/debug. In production this will be the directory where your application starts. As I have said you need to pass a fully qualified filename (I.E. with path). In alternative you could define a destination path with your config file and add this path to the filename passed in.

Comment: No there is no reply button. Simply edit your question with the appropriate changes made and post a comment about the news. (By the way if, in a comment, you type an @ followed by the name of the person to which you want to reply, that person will be immediately notified

Comment: Ive overwritten my original post